# Descriptor 'utctimetuple' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, timestamp, interpolation

I'm trying to create a function that takes datetime.datetime objects and returns a UTC timestamp.

```
import numpy as np
import calendar
import time
from datetime import datetime   

def toTimestamp(d):
    return calendar.timegm(datetime.utctimetuple(d))

X = np.array(toTimestamp(SunAziInterpTimes))
XP = np.array(toTimestamp(SunAziMat[:,0]))
FP = np.array(toTimestamp(SunAziMat[:,1]))
ts[:] = np.interp(X,XP,FP)
```

SunAziInterpTimes is a numpy.ndarray of shape (20000,), and contains
datetime.datetime objects.

SunAziMat is a numpy.ndarray of shape (10000,2). The first column contains only datetime.datetime objects and the second column contains only floats.

Whenever I run the code above, I get an error saying:

> 'descriptor 'utctimetuple' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but
>   received a 'numpy.ndarray''

However, if from within the Python console I try

```
toTimestamp(SunAziInterpTimes[0])
```

It works.

How do I modify my code so that I correctly parse the datetime objects to the toTimestamp function so that I'm able to create the X, XP arrays containing the UTC timestamped data?

Comment: Datetime code only works with one date at time, not a while list, and not an array.  So you'll have to iterate.  But to use these arrays in `interp' you'll have to use `np.datetime64` arrays, not arrays of datetime objects.

Comment: Thanks! I used a for loop to iterate over the arrays and it works now. 

Since my function converts the datetime object to a floating point timestamp, I was able to just use numpy arrays in the interp function.